# JScrollPane - Smooth Scrolling

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane

I have a JScrollPane with a moderately high block increment (125). I would like to apply smooth/slow scrolling to it so it doesn't jump (or skip) when scrolling. How can I do this?

I was thinking of scrolling like Windows 8.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `javax.swing.Timer` during the scroll to achieve the smooth scrolling effect. If you are triggering this from outside the component, somthing like this will work (where `component` is the component within the `JScrollPane`):

```
final int target = visible.y;
final Rectangle current = component.getVisibleRect();
final int start = current.y;
final int delta = target - start;
final int msBetweenIterations = 10;

Timer scrollTimer = new Timer(msBetweenIterations, new ActionListener() {
    int currentIteration = 0;
    final long animationTime = 150; // milliseconds
    final long nsBetweenIterations = msBetweenIterations * 1000000; // nanoseconds
    final long startTime = System.nanoTime() - nsBetweenIterations; // Make the animation move on the first iteration
    final long targetCompletionTime = startTime + animationTime * 1000000;
    final long targetElapsedTime = targetCompletionTime - startTime;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        long timeSinceStart = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        double percentComplete = Math.min(1.0, (double) timeSinceStart / targetElapsedTime);

        double factor = getFactor(percentComplete);
        current.y = (int) Math.round(start + delta * factor);
        component.scrollRectToVisible(current);
        if (timeSinceStart >= targetElapsedTime) {
            ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
        }
    }
});
scrollTimer.setInitialDelay(0);
scrollTimer.start();
```

The `getFactor` method is a conversion from linear to an easing function and would be implemented as one of these depending on how you want it to feel:

```
private double snap(double percent) {
    return 1;
}

private double linear(double percent) {
    return percent;
}

private double easeInCubic(double percent) {
    return Math.pow(percent, 3);
}

private double easeOutCubic(double percent) {
    return 1 - easeInCubic(1 - percent);
}

private double easeInOutCubic(double percent) {
    return percent < 0.5
            ? easeInCubic(percent * 2) / 2
            : easeInCubic(percent * -2 + 2) / -2 + 1;
}
```

This could probably be adapted to work within a component too so when the user scrolls it does something along these lines.

Or, if possible, you could use JavaFX which has much better support for animation than Swing.